# Redux state not updating

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-realtime-database

My reducer won't update my Redux state tree and I haven't found the solution so I was hoping to get some help. This is my code:

**Reducer**

```
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable'
import { loadFirebaseData } from '../actions/firebaseActions'

const FETCH_FIREBASE_DATA = 'FETCH_FIREBASE_DATA'

const initialState = Immutable({})

export default function firebaseReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_FIREBASE_DATA:
    return state
    .set('firebaseData', fetchData(action))
  }
  return state
}


function fetchData(action) {
  return {
    firebaseData: action.firebaseData
  }
}
```

**App**

```
class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchFirebaseData('gallery')
  }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log('state',state.firebaseReducer)
  return {
    galleryItems: state.firebaseReducer
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(firebaseActions, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

And if I were to log out the execution of the reducer:

```
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable'
import { loadFirebaseData } from '../actions/firebaseActions'

const FETCH_FIREBASE_DATA = 'FETCH_FIREBASE_DATA'

const initialState = Immutable({})

export default function firebaseReducer(state = initialState, action) {

  console.log(1)
  switch (action.type) {

    case FETCH_FIREBASE_DATA:
    console.log(2)
    return state
    .set('firebaseData', fetchData(action))
  }

  console.log(3)
  console.log('state', state)
  return state
}


function fetchData(action) {
  return {
    firebaseData: action.firebaseData
  }
}
```

The console shows:

```
1
3
state: Object {__immutable_invariants_hold: true}
1
3
Object {__immutable_invariants_hold: true}
Object {__immutable_invariants_hold: true}
1
2
```

So at the last step, the state doesn't get updated. Any thoughts on why? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using wrong function to make changes to your store. Since you are using `seamless-immutable`, `set` function expect as a parameters 2 strings: key and value. In your code you pass to it string and an object.

According to [seamless-immutable documentation](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable/blob/master/README.md) to set `state.firebaseData` to value passed by `action.firebaseData` use merge function with an object as:

```
export default function firebaseReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_FIREBASE_DATA:
      return state
        .merge(fetchData(action))
  }
  return state
}
```

Other issue I see with your provided example is that in `mapStateToPros` function you are accessing member `firebaseReducer` of the state which is nowhere to be found. Did you intended to map it the `state.firebaseData`?